# How to check the battery level of devices connected via Bluetooth in OS X

Tags: macos, drivers, battery, bluetooth

I have a set of Bluetooth headphones that I use with my iPhone and Macbook (OS X Yosemite).

On my iPhone, a little battery meter pops up next to the Bluetooth logo each time I'm connect the headphones.  The OS X has no such option (to my knowledge), so I'm wondering if anyone else has had the same experience.

The only potential solution I came across was the Battery Tracker on the Mac App Store. It is not clear whether it supports all Bluetooth devices (and not just standard peripherals), and I would rather not pay the $1.99 to find out.

My gut is telling me that this information (battery level) has to be accessible somewhere / somehow. I'm interested in finding a solution from a practical standpoint, but am equally as interested in understanding how it would be/is achieved from a technical standpoint.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts/insights ! Thanks

**Edit:**

After doing a little more homework, I found out that my headphones have the [A2DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_.28A2DP.29) profile.  And here is a screenshot of the device profile from my mac's System Information.

[image]

**RSSI** seems like the only thing that could have been a battery meter (everything else is booleans or id's), but from what I've read it seems to be a metric for signal strength. Getting closer, just need to figure out what the battery metric/param/variable is called and how to read it.

Comment: The Apple Wireless Trackpad shows 'Battery Level' in the System Information (and on the Bluetooth menu).

Comment: Oh really.. nothing for my Powerbeats headphones :/

Answer (score -2):

RSSI is a measure of the signal strength, not battery level.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the actual question consider putting things like this in a comment in the future.